# Singularity Grid System into static grid

Tags: css, grid, singularitygs

I´d like to turn all values into 'px' (grid, gutter, ...). Chance fluid to a static grid.

I try ["Fixed Gutters](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Creating-Grids#fixed-gutters)" but this works not for the whole grid, just gutters.

How can I do this?

Thanks
Ogni

Answer (score 2):

Just give your containing element a fixed width.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column-1">a column</div>
</div>

.grid {
  width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user2242314. Than `column-1` get a width value in "%", too. This value should be in "px", too.

Comment: @ogni, Yes, the units for column-1 will be in %. It will be the same width as your px value though. I see no need to generate px column values as % will have the same result. If you feel strongly that you still need px you can create your own output mode.